# enable pinch zoom on a single image/div when its dissable using viewport meta for the rest of the page

Tags: zooming, viewport

Is it possable to exempt an img or div from the viewport meta so that only one image would be able to be zoomed in on similar to a normal jquery image zoom but just using the pinch in / pinch out

Comment: found a solution using a jquery plugin, its a premium one but works on ios which quite a few didnt..

http://codecanyon.net/item/smooth-zoom-pan-jquery-image-viewer/511142